# Declaring a Struct in C: Why do I have to Specify the Name Twice?

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef

In order to declare a struct in C, I have been using

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

and then defining it at some point below.

Why do I have to specify the name of the struct (`Foo`) twice?

Comment: This isn't declaring a struct per se. You can avoid doing that and use the full `struct Foo` type name. Some code guidelines even have that as a tenet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is

```
typedef old_type new_type
```

so for

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

`struct Foo` is the old type and `Foo` is the new type, so whenever you type `Foo` it is really an alias for `struct Foo`.

Comment: Oh, ok then. So how does typedef differ from #define then? (of course, that might just be worth its own question, but is it a simple enough explanation to drop here?) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`struct Foo` is the type that are creating a new type alias for.  The last `Foo` is the name of the new type.  If your struct declaration is visible, then you can write the type definition and struct declaration combination like this to avoid the duplicated `Foo`:

```
typedef struct {
  ...
} Foo;
```

Comment: Not my DV, but that will only work if the `struct` definition is visible.  It won't work for an [opaque `struct`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).

Comment: I will note it above, thanks.   Personally, I like the separate name spaces so I don't think that I ever use typedef.

Comment: @AndrewHenle What does "DV" stand for?

Comment: "DV" -> "downvote".  You had one for a while there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Duh... of course.  Even if it was, no worries, I would still like you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify two names. You can introduce an incomplete struct type just like this:

```
struct Foo;
```

that's it. Or a complete one:

```
struct Foo { int x; };
```

Neither of these declarations introduce a name into the scope; they introduce a struct *tag*.

If you introduce a struct tag, you must use the `struct` keyword everywhere to refer to it, e.g.

```
struct Foo f;

void fun(struct Foo *param);
```

The `typedef` is used in order not to have to write `struct Foo` everywhere. The type name doesn't have to be the same as the tag:

```
typedef struct Foo_s Foo;

Foo f;
void fun(Foo *param);
```

The C++ dialect of C changes the rules; in C++ `struct Foo` introduces `Foo` into the scope as a type name, and as a tag (for C compatibility).

One reason you might see `typedef struct Foo Foo` might be that the code started as C++, looking like this:

```
struct Foo;              // Originally C++ only header file.
void fun(Foo *param);
```

Then a requirement came along that C had to be supported, at least in header files. In C, the `Foo` type is not declared:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;  // Fix for C.

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define extern_c extern "C"   // C compatible linkage for fun
#endif

void fun(Foo *param);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Though C++ may seem more convenient in this regard, its object system absolutely punishes the user with repetitions of the same identifier, like you wouldn't believe.

To define a basic class skeleton with a constructor and destructor which are not inlined in the class declaration, we have to repeat the name seven times:

```
class foo {
public:
  foo();
  ~foo();
}; 

foo::foo()
{
}

foo::~foo()
{
}
```

Good thing the C++ programmer is at least spared from having to write `class foo *fooptr` everywhere, right?